# React passing array subcomponent as a prop or importing it in each array item

Tags: reactjs, import, react-props

I have a component (**ArrayComponent**) that renders an array of data rows (**RowComponents**) that wraps the line inside a **SubComponent**.
Is there any significant performance difference whether I import that impo  on top level Component (ArrayComponent) and pass it as props to RowComponent component or import that SubComponent on each RowComponent? The array might have thousands of items in it.

Here is a very [simplified example](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-architecture-b03pf?file=/src/App.js) of both ways.

Having it imported in RowComponent would simplify few other things (not shown here) and I would prefer to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use webpack or or a similar bundler (create-react-app gives you webpack out of the box) your code will be bundled into a single .js file and import statements are no longer relevant.

If this is the case, passing the subcomponent as a prop just adds complexity with no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

This is good example of props drilling. The reasonable solution to this would be using your own custom hooks. such as below;

```
const useMyArrayHook = () => {
 const myArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"];
 return myArray;
}
```

Now, rather passing this array into multiple components and sub-components, you can use in the target component where you want to use it, in your case in `RowComponentWithImport.js` and `RowComponentWithoutImport.js` components.

Comment: I don't see how this answer has anything to do with my question. Except for the props-drilling part. But that hook which returns an array wasn't at all what I was asking about. Check the accepted answer. That answers my question 100%.

Comment: From React point of view, passing props to multiple sub-components do add the complexity and side effects which impacts performance. Imagine prop changes in any of the component causes all the sub-components having it, to re-render.

Comment: Ok, I see your point now, but passing that array had nothing to do with my question. I was asking about SubComponent. The prop drilling part was relevant and that was exactly what I was wanting to avoid by importing the SubComponent inside the RowComponent, but I wanted to know if importing it possibly thousands of times would cause any performance problems compared to importing it once and passing as a prop. And yes, my question was probably badly written. Thank you for the answer in any case.